# OpenLayers generating clientside PDFs

Tags: openlayers

I am currently working on a solution to generate clientside PDFs from OpenLayers content. The experience is okay so far, but I am having a bit of a hassle.

The abstract is as follows:

- Calculating the amount of pixels needed to fill a given space on paper
- Temporarily set the `map` to given resolution
- read canvas
- do print stuff
- reset map to previous resolution

In code:

```
      var mapSizeForPrint = [
        // in pixel
        Math.round(this.pdf.width * pixelsPerMapMillimeter),
        Math.round(this.pdf.height * pixelsPerMapMillimeter)
      ];
      ...
      var map = this.openLayersMap();
      ...
      this.mapExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(this.mapSize);
      ...
      this.rendercompleteListener = map.once("rendercomplete", event => {
       //Do printing magic
      }
      map.setSize(mapSizeForPrint);
      map.getView().fit(this.mapExtent, { size: mapSizeForPrint });
```

If anyone is interested in the (dirty) details: *full code is available as open source* [here](http://hg.intevation.de/gemma/file/tip/client/src/components/Pdftool.vue#l252)

That works to a certain degree.

- scaling to 80 DPI, I get an expected subset of the map
- scaling to 120 DPI, I get a relatively expected subset of the map
- scaling to 200 DPI, getting an unexpected result

[image: application]
[image: 80DPI]
[image: 200DPI]

Currently I assume, that I get the "same" dataset for any given resolution - i.e. the visible center of the `80DPI` version is "the same" as the `200DPI` only that it doesn't fit on screen; but that seems not to be the case.

Does anybody give me a hint in which direction to look? Perhaps I have some false assumptions which I currently do not see or do not see, how to overcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because in OpenLayers 5 by default `fit` constrains the resolution to an integer zoom level.  That can be fixed by adding `constrainResolution: false` to the options.  Also note that `calculateExtent()` and `fit()` do not give the desired result when the view is rotated so you could replace them completely by setting resolution so in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html

```
    var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

    map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
      var canvas = event.context.canvas;
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
      pdf.save('map.pdf');
      // Reset original map size
      map.setSize(size);
      map.getView().fit(extent, {size: size});
      exportButton.disabled = false;
      document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    });

    // Set print size
    var printSize = [width, height];
    map.setSize(printSize);
    map.getView().fit(extent, {size: printSize});
```

becomes

```
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();

    map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
      var canvas = event.context.canvas;
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
      pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
      pdf.save('map.pdf');
      // Reset original map size
      map.setSize(size);
      map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution);
      exportButton.disabled = false;
      document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
    });

    // Set print size
    var printSize = [width, height];
    map.setSize(printSize);
    var scaling = Math.min(width / size[0], height / size[1]);
    map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution / scaling);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm.